# Desktop Window Manager extreme GPU usage (> 20% with RTX 3070)

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

So I noticed today that Desktop Window Manager is having a very high GPU usage when I move windows around or just do simple rudimentary tasks with my PC. When I do nothing at all, GPU usage idles between 1-2% (which is already way too high for a RTX 3070) and when I move windows around on my desktop (e.g. windows explorer) it spikes up to 20%.

**Does anyone know how I can fix this?**

**System specs**

- Windows 10
- GPU: RTX 3070
- CPU: Intel i7 11700K
- RAM: 32GB @ 3200mhz
- Storage: Samsung 980 PRO 1TB
- Displays: 1) 2560 x 1440 144hz G-sync enabled, 2) 1920 x 1080 60hz

**Things I have already tried and that don't work:**

- Reinstall windows. This in combination with the fact that the problem only shows once I start moving windows makes it highly unlikely that it's malware.
- Update to the latest drivers
- Lower process priority in task manager
- Disable animations & transparency effects to see if anything changes (they don't)
- Google for hours to find a useful solution
- I compared this to the PC of my wife. She has a dual monitor setup as well, both screens 1080p. Graphics card a very old GTX 650 TI. Doing similar task, GPU usage is not even 2%. So it's definitely an issue with my system.
- Try and switch Desktop Window Manager to `power saver` mode in Windows' Graphics Settings which should trigger it to use my processor's integrated graphics. However, it does not switch and continues to use the RTX 3070.
- Install older driver version (I went back all the way to a 2020 december driver)
- Turn on `Hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured out what the "problem" is;

In NVidia Control Panel one can set a `Power management mode`. By default the value is `normal` which causes the GPU's clock speeds to drop by 90% when it is not under load (and thus saving a significant amount of power).

When dragging windows around, it is not a heavy load for the GPU and thus it doesn't increase to a more performant mode. However, when your system is measuring the GPU usage, it does so from this low-power state. The usage will appear as a very high percentage, even though the actual usage is insignificant.

Setting the power management mode to `prefer maximum performance` will cause the GPU to always run at it's boost speed regardless of the load. This will also show in task manager: the measured usage drops to below 3% on a high refresh rate high resolution monitor.

Another setting that may affect this is in Windows 10's `graphics settings`. Here you can select individual programs and indicate whether they should use `performance` or `power saving` mode.